# Add-AzureADGroupMember error "Error occurred while executing AddGroupMember"

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

We re experiencing a consistent error adding members to a security group

```
refObjectId=Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName $UserEmail
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId [securitygroupID] -RefObjectId $refObjectId.Id
```

script above succeeds about half of the time and fails about half throwing :

> Exception: Error occurred while executing AddGroupMember StatusCode:
>   BadRequest ErrorCode: Request_BadRequest Message: One or more added
>   object references already exist for the following modified properties:
>   'members'.

This group typically has hundreds of users that primarily have a common name (i.e. Temporary User) but unique UPNs (i.e. user12345@) I am assuming when Add-AzureADGroupMember runs, it is first verifying whether member already exists in the group and is checking username (will have duplicates) rather than objectid (no duplicates)

Any suggestions to force command to use ObjectID for verification to prevent false positive for member already exists?

Comment: Same usernames? or same Name ? Users in Azure AD all have different usernames. Check if the user is already in the group.

Comment: Same Name (Temporary User) - different UserNames (user12345@....) User is not already in the group as the user is dynamically created in a new resource group about an hour before this script is run in our automation process.  I suspect that when it is checking to see if the user already exists in the group it is checking Name, not UPN, thus giving me  false error that the user already exists.

Comment: Hi, @Terri Harmon. I did a test , I could add a member which name is as same as a member in that group. I'm not clear that how you create your Temporary user,  You can try to use `Get-AzureADGroupMember`  to check if the user is still in that group.

Comment: Thanks Wayne - that is what is so confusing about this issue - it works sometimes and does not work others. I can't find a root cause. Would you know where I could get any of the details about how the Add-AzureADGroupMember does the verification check to determine if the user is already in the group? I haven't been able to find source links for it.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the specified error occurs if specified user is *already a member of a group*.

Regarding:

> Any suggestions to force command to use ObjectID for verification to
>   prevent false positive for member already exists?

the following approach could be considered:

a) utilize [`Get-AzureADGroupMember` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0) to retrieve *all* the existing members beforehand, for example:

```
$targetGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '<group name>'"
$groupMembers = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $targetGroup.ObjectId -All $true
```

b) verify whether a user belong to group before invoking `Add-AzureADGroupMember`:

```
$targetUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "Mail eq '<email>'"
$existingMember =  $groupMembers | Where-Object { $_.ObjectId -eq $targetUser.ObjectId }
if(!$existingMember){
   Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $targetGroup.ObjectId -RefObjectId $targetUser.ObjectId  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While Vadim's answer is quite good, I propose a smaller, more simple answer to this problem:

```
# Get the group that we want to modify.
$Group = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq 'GroupName'"
# Get all of the group members.
$Members = $Group | Get-AzureADGroupMember -All $true
# Get the user that you want to check
$User = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "Mail eq 'email'"

# Compare the Member list Object IDs with the user's Object ID via the -contains operator. (You don't need .ObjectID, but this could make the function faster in large jobs as you don't need to compare all values, just the one that you know is unique)
$IsUserInGroup = $Members.ObjectID -contains $User.ObjectID
```

$IsUserInGroup will return true if the user is in the group, and false if they are not. To invert this, either do `(-NOT $IsUserInGroup)` or use `-notcontains`

Answer (score 1):

I hit this thread and discovered that the Get-AzureADGroupMember only returns the first 100 entries by default, you gotta have the '-All $true' switch to get all entries.  My coding is very similar to NathanWindish only I make use of arrays for error checking.

```
# Get the groupID
$grpID = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "MyGroupName" | select -ExpandProperty ObjectID

# Get Group members
$grpMbrList = @(Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $grpID -All $true)

# Get UserID - this should only return one user, but setting in an array means you can easily check
$adUser= @(Get-AzureADUser | ?{$_.mail -eq "user@doman.com"})

# confirm you only have a single result
if ($aduser.count -eq 1) {
 
 # check the group
 if ($grpMbrList.objectId -contains $adUser.objectID) {
   user exists in group do stuff
 } 
 else {
   user does not exist in the group, do other stuff
 }

}
```